# Nunit test project cannot load System.Windows.Forms assembly to test a windows form based application targeting .Net 4.6.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit, tdd, .net-framework-version

We have a Nunit test project targeting .Net Core 3.0 .
This test project writes tests against a windows form based project which has target framework of 4.6.1 and a class library project also targeting 4.6.1.

Although I can write test for the class library project but am unable to test the windows form based project. 
While running test it always stops with an error,

"System.BadImageFormatException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (0x80131058)
      ----> System.BadImageFormatException : Cannot load a reference assembly for execution"

Any thoughts?

Comment: A .NET Core project cannot reference a .NET Framework assembly and vice versa. They both can reference assemblies of their own platform target or .NET Standard libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes it seems this is the case. Any suggestion of how to use Nunit to test windows application (Of course having forms) @GyörgyKőszeg

Comment: Targeting .NET 4.6.1 in test.csproj?

Comment: When you create a test project, i.e Nunit test project under .Net Core environment its selected as a Console application. I believe the solution would be to change the project type to Class library and only that way I can change the target framework to .Net framework 4.6.1. Thoughts @GyörgyKőszeg?

Comment: A test project can target both .NET Core and .NET Framework. Feel free to change the `<TargetFramework>` value to `net461`.

Comment: Typical exception when you have assemblies compiled with another platform or sometimes when not specifying target framework, I think Kirsten is on the right path

Answer (score 1):

In my case I am  looking into the following links https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/553509/how-to-fix-systembadimageformatexception.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/553509/how-to-fix-systembadimageformatexception.html

I notice that my library project assemblies look different to what I expect
[image: expecting]

[image: Assemblies]

[My Answer]
I just edited the library project file and added

```
<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
<Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
```